# What is the name for the forested areas in mountains below the treeline?

Tags: mountains, terminology, forest

Taiga is the Russian word for big areas of forest wilderness in high latitude regions. What about forests in the mountains? What is the name for the forested areas in mountains which are below the treeline?

For instance, see the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forests directly below the [alpine tree line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_line#Alpine) are high-elevation or Montane forests.  See more about [Montane ecology here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montane_ecology).

[image: treeline image]  Image from http://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/global-treeline-position-15897370

Comment: Montane is the branch of ecology dealing with mountains.

Answer (score 1):

Between timberline and treeline lies "krumholtz", a German word meaning broken or bent wood".

Great place to hike.

Comment: Krumholtz is mentioned on the wikipedia page for Montane.

Answer (score 0):

The US National Park Service refers to a forested area directly below tree line as "subalpine forest." ([NPS - Subalpine Forest)](https://www.nps.gov/olym/learn/nature/subalpine-forests.htm).